# express js setup global URL activity hook

Tags: express

Some API calls my webhook written in Express, can I see any activity that the other party is trying to execute on my server? In other words just output to console if the remote is trying to GET or POST anything?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe look into express-winston for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what your web app is doing, without modifying it's source code, by using the `DEBUG` environment variable:

```
DEBUG=express:* node app.js
```

This will turn on the internal express [logging](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html).